# How to convert MongoEngine class in Pedantic Basemodel in python (fastapi)

Tags: python, mongoengine, fastapi

Currently i am struggling to pass mongoengine model in a post call by fastapi which only accepts pedantic models. But i have written my mongo models in mongoengine ODM. And if i try to pass these mongoengine models in apis then it throws error

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str = None
    price: float
    tax: float = None


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/items/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item
```

Answer (score 2):

**Import mongoengine and uvicorn**

```
from mongoengine import *
import uvicorn
```

**Create a MongoDB connection**

```
DATABASE_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
db=DATABASE_URI+"/mydatabase"
connect(host=db)
```

**Declare a MongoEngine Class similar to your Item Class**

```
class MongoItem(Document):
    name=StringField()
    description= StringField()
    price=FloatField()
    tax= FloatField()
```

**Add a one line of code to store a item in MongoDB**

```
    MongoItem(**item.dict()).save()
```

---

**The complete code of main.py:**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from mongoengine import *
import uvicorn


DATABASE_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
db=DATABASE_URI+"/mydatabase"
connect(host=db)

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str = None
    price: float
    tax: float = None

class MongoItem(Document):
    name=StringField()
    description= StringField()
    price=FloatField()
    tax= FloatField()
    
app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/items/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    mongoitem=MongoItem(**item.dict()).save()
    return item
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reload=True)
```

**Or even shorter using a DynamicDocument Class**

```
class MongoItem(DynamicDocument):
    pass
```

Comment: It may cause code duplication. Is there another way ?

Comment: Some mongodb libraries integrate with pydantic, In my opinion your database models and API schema should stay separate, it may look like code duplication, but they're different entities and serve different purposes.